# Can compressing individual attributes in a document reclaim space in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, attributes, compression, document

I have a MongoDB 3.0 document (configured with WiredTiger Snappy compression) that looks like this:

```
annotPatch": {
    "_id":"1_789681__GGAATGGAAT",
    "ensemblVer": 87,
    "VEPCacheVer": 86,
    "compressed": 0,
    "ct" :  [{"gn" : "RP11-206L10.9", "ensg" : "ENSG00000237491"}],
    "xrefs" : [{"id" : "ENST00000585745", "src" : "ensemblTranscript"}] 
}
```

Let's say I compress some attributes in millions of documents like this to make them look like this:

```
annotPatch": {
    "_id":"1_789681__GGAATGGAAT",
    "ensemblVer": 87,
    "VEPCacheVer": 86,
    "compressed": 1,
    "compressData": "Compressed CT and xRef"
}
```

Would doing the above operation reclaim disk space in any meaningful way?

Comment: Please add your code in Code tag, its help other to read your question better

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question.

Comment: the site editor have a button for code in your question, its better you use that

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using, and what storage engine? If you are using a storage engine that compresses data by default (eg. WiredTiger), compressed values will likely increase disk space as compared to the default configuration. Irrespective of storage engine, compressing some embedded data will also reduce usability (eg. you cannot index or search the `compressData` without retrieving it first).

Comment: Thank you, Stennie!